# Getting TypeError: float argument required in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am passing a floating exponent value to a python function and later using it:

```
def estimateFit(infile, fsrmin):
    test=isfloat(fsrmin)
    print "fsrmin test for isfloat: %s" %test
    flimit = 30e9;
    print "flimit = %.3e" %flimit
    float(fsrmin)
    print "fsrmin = %.3e" %fsrmin
```

I am calling this function from another python program as:

```
     fsrmin = sys.argv[3]
R, I, w = srf.estimateFit(infile,fsrmin)
```

I am always getting this error:

```
>     print "fsrmin = %.3e" %fsrmin 
TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

As you can see I tried to  convert to float in the program. Anything I am missing

Comment: I am doing it inside the final function estimateFit.. line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not assign `fsrmin` to `float(fsrmin)`. i suggest you use:

```
fsrmin = sys.argv[3]    # fsrmin is a str for now
fsrmin = float(fsrmin)  # here we convert to float
R, I, w = srf.estimateFit(infile,fsrmin)
```

the statement `float(fsrmin)` does not change the variable `fsrmin`. it will raise a `ValueError` if the string `fsrmin` can not be interpreted as float.

Comment: But I am already doing this before the print, but still getting the error

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood the first time. I will try it and confirm